# How to set fetch-size in Spring-Data-JDBC

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I use Spring-Data-**JDBC** (not JPA) and want to set the fetch-size.

I know that the the classic `org.springframwork.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` has a `setFetchSize(int)` method, but I have Spring-Data-JDBC repository:

```
org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;
org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.Query;

/** This is a Spring Data <b>JDBC</b> (JDBC not JPA!). */      
public interface UserDao extends  Repository<User, Long> {
  
    @Query(value = UserRowMapper.SELECT_BY_NAME_STATEMENT
           rowMapperClass = UserRowMapper.class)
    Optional<User> findByName(String name);
}
```

and this is the relevant part of the configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcRepositories 
public class AppConfigSpringDataJdbc extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration {
   @Autowired
   private DataSource dataSource;

   @Bean
   public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate() {
       return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(this.dataSource);
   }
}
```

So my question is: **How/Where to set the sql query fetch-size when using Spring-Data-JDBC, either by query or in general?**

*(The common solutions for Spring-Data-JPA will not work, because there is no `persistence.xml` or `javax.persistence.QueryHint`annotation because it is JDBC)*

Comment: In general you can set it by accessing inner jdbc template of `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` - `jdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate().setFetchSize(100);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` using custom `JdbcTemplate`.

```
@Bean
JdbcOperations jdbcOperations(DataSource dataSource) {
    final var jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(100);
    return jdbcTemplate;
}

@Bean
NamedParameterJdbcOperations namedParameterJdbcOperations(JdbcOperations operations) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(operations);
}
```

Comment: I did what you recommend in the comment to the question: 
`@BeanNamedParameterJdbcOperations operations() {
   var namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(this.dataSource);
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate().setFetchSize(this.jdbcRepositoryFetchSize);    return namedParameterJdbcTemplate; }`

Comment: @Ralph I'd prefer variant in answer cause it is cleaner and more possibility to customize `jdbcTemplate`